# Django: how to validate the complete form

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a form which has two fields for Integers:

```
class DemoForm(forms.Form):
b_one = forms.IntegerField(
    error_messages={
       'required':'Please enter a valid number.'
    },
    label = 'NumberOne',
    required = True,
    help_text = 'e.g. 266492'
)
b_two = forms.IntegerField(
    error_messages={
       'required':'Please enter a valid number.'
    },
    label = 'NumberTwo',
    required = True,
    help_text = 'e.g. 262865',
)
```

and I am validating these fields as

```
def clean_b_one(self):
    self.validate_form(self.cleaned_data['b_one'])

def clean_b_two(self):
    self.validate_form(self.cleaned_data['b_two'])
```

Now what I want to do is in `validate_form` I check, if these numbers exists in database, else raising `forms.ValidationError`

But what I also want to do some other validations when these form fields are valid, basically some check on the form based on input and raise some custom errors, where can I add logic? or what is the best way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do individual field verifying in `clean_b_one` like you have, and raise `ValidationError`s if something doesn't fit. Or override the `clean` method to do cross-field checking. General documentation to be found [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/).